# Image and PDF URLs are appended with -v0 in rendered JSP code when published with Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, 2013-sp1-hr1, dd4t-java

We are using Tridion 2013 SP1.
When publishing the components with workflow the urls are created with -v0 and it is not loading any content. Please suggest how to resolve this type of issues.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Whenever component is in a workflow, it gets checked-out, so v0 version (minor version) is created. And yes, this is a standard behavior. When component leaves workflow, minor version is no longer there.

Besides, I see that you publish binary with TCM id in file name. If this gives you problem, you can remove TCM id from filename during publishing.